# Consume Rest API on same ip but different port

Tags: javascript, rest, apache2

Let's suppose a backend application, which exposes some Rest API, running on a Jetty webserver at address 192.168.1.10:8889.

I would like to have a frontend application (html/javascript only, on a apache2 webserver) running at the same IP but on a different port (e.g. 8000), which should consume the API exposed by the backend application.

How can i get this architecture working without get into "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'" error?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should install a nginx proxy.

configure it as a reverse proxy you can see documentation here :

https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/

You can search on google for more specific documentation on what you want to do.